# Find the points in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ where $F$ doesn't have rank $2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Consider the map $F: \mathbb{RP}^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^3$ given by $$[x:y:z] \to [x^2+y^2:xy:x^2+z^2:xz]$$

Find the points in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ where $F$ doesn't have rank $2$

I am confused about how to find the differential of the map. Any hint would suffice.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What definition of differential are you using?

Comment: I was thinking of looking at curves

Comment: To make things easier, use charts $\phi, \eta$to work in Euclidean space. Then $\eta^{-1} \circ F \circ \phi$ is a map between $\mathbb R^2 $ and $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Use as maps $(x,y) \mapsto [x : y : 1]$, $(x,y) \mapsto [x :1 : y]$, and so on.